# C++ interface for computation that may or may not transfer ownership of its result

Tags: c++, caching, interface, signature, ownership

I have a computation that returns const references to collections that can be megabytes in size. Some of the results exist higher up on the stack, some results should be computed and cached, and some results should be computed and not cached. In the first two cases the function can return by const lvalue reference, but in the last case the caller needs to take ownership of the value, which will not persist in the cache.

I'd like to provide a single function interface for this computation, so that callers don't need to first try lazily computing a result owned by the cache, before falling back on taking ownership of a non-cached result. Additionally, I'd like to avoid the use of shared pointers to keep ownership clear.

### Solutions considered:

1) Assignment to out parameter if ownership must be transferred, as in the following signature:

```
const Result& LookupOrCompute(Cache& cache, const Input& input, Result& optionalOwnership)
```

2) Writing a custom smart pointer with two subclasses, one that assumes ownership and one that does not.

I'm leaning towards the first option. While preserving type and memory safety, is there a cleaner, more idiomatic way to do this in C++?

Comment: If results are rather small values (e.g. `int`, `double`) it's probably not worth to return references. If results are instead composed data of possibly significant size then your function may return a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to result. Thus, it is possible to cache data in one function (and return always the address of that same cached data) as well as to return the address of a new created result for each call in another function. Btw. `std::shared_ptr` will help to prevent memory leaks concerning results which are not anymore used.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `std::shared_ptr` provides shared ownership (in opposition(?) to transferred). For cached data, this may require that result data is made `const`.

Comment: The size of the data is on the order of megabytes, so best not to copy. I'm hoping to avoid shared_ptr, so that its clear what's in the cache, and what will be deallocated immediately (but if the above solutions weren't viable shared_ptr would certainly be my go to)

Comment: Another reason to avoid shared_ptr in this case is that some of the data that may be returned as a result is higher up on the callstack and not on the heap

Comment: To store data on stack "on the order of megabytes", you probably need additional settings for your compiler. The defaults grant usually a rather limited stack size.

Comment: With such and similar cases in mind, I once implemented my own (intrusive) smart-pointers (before `std::shared_ptr` became popular). They are not complete fail-save but work quite good in my daily work. A draw-back is that my ref-ptr even may loose its pointee if it "goes out of scope". (At least, the ref-ptr is reset to `nullptr` correctly in this case.)

Comment: Seriously: If usual data size of results is mega bytes and the only reason against `std::shared_ptr` is intended storage on stack I would consider to drop the latter. Many allocations of tiny snippets would concern me. A few allocations of mega byte chunks is probably something which does not hurt.

Comment: @Scheff, thanks for your responses. I probably should have been more clear in my original question and subsequent responses (have reworded the first paragraph). The Result type is a small collection (~24 bytes) that owns a lot of heap memory (on the order of megabytes). It's just that some of these Results are const local variables higher up on the call-stack, some are owned by the cache, and some are computed temporarily and discarded.